# Adding face overlay filter to Kurento app

Tags: kurento

I want to add custom OpenCV module to my Kurento app but first of all, with training purposes, I want to try to **integrate the FaceOverlay filter** instead.

I have a problem when I put it in One2One tutorial.  The tutorial itself works perfectly but **when I create and connect the filter to the endpoints the communication cannot be established and sometimes the connection with Kurento Media Server is closed with no reason.**

I would appreciate if someone can help me.  To reproduce my issue you can get the node.js version of the [One2One tutorial](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-node/tree/master/kurento-one2one-call) and replace the `CallMediaPipeline.prototype.createPipeline` with the code I've attached.

Thanks.

```js
CallMediaPipeline.prototype.createPipeline = function(callerId, calleeId, ws, callback) {
    var self = this;
    getKurentoClient(function(error, kurentoClient) {
        if (error) {
            return callback(error);
        }

        kurentoClient.create('MediaPipeline', function(error, pipeline) {
            if (error) {
                return callback(error);
            }

            pipeline.create('WebRtcEndpoint', {useDataChannels: true}, function(error, callerWebRtcEndpoint) {
                if (error) {
                    pipeline.release();
                    return callback(error);
                }

                pipeline.create('FaceOverlayFilter', function(error, faceOverlayFilter) {
                    if (error) {
                        return callback(error);
                    }
                    faceOverlayFilter.setOverlayedImage(url.format(asUrl) + 'img/mario-wings.png',
                            -0.35, -1.2, 1.6, 1.6, function(error) {
                        if (error) {
                            console.log("Error assigning image to filter");
                            return callback(error);
                        }
                    });
                    if (candidatesQueue[callerId]) {
                        while(candidatesQueue[callerId].length) {
                            var candidate = candidatesQueue[callerId].shift();
                            callerWebRtcEndpoint.addIceCandidate(candidate);
                        }
                    }

                    callerWebRtcEndpoint.on('OnIceCandidate', function(event) {
                        var candidate = kurento.register.complexTypes.IceCandidate(event.candidate);
                        userRegistry.getById(callerId).ws.send(JSON.stringify({
                            id : 'iceCandidate',
                            candidate : candidate
                        }));
                    });

                    pipeline.create('WebRtcEndpoint', {useDataChannels: true}, function(error, calleeWebRtcEndpoint) {
                        if (error) {
                            pipeline.release();
                            return callback(error);
                        }

                        if (candidatesQueue[calleeId]) {
                            while(candidatesQueue[calleeId].length) {
                                var candidate = candidatesQueue[calleeId].shift();
                                calleeWebRtcEndpoint.addIceCandidate(candidate);
                            }
                        }

                        calleeWebRtcEndpoint.on('OnIceCandidate', function(event) {
                            var candidate = kurento.register.complexTypes.IceCandidate(event.candidate);
                            userRegistry.getById(calleeId).ws.send(JSON.stringify({
                                id : 'iceCandidate',
                                candidate : candidate
                            }));
                        });

                        callerWebRtcEndpoint.connect(faceOverlayFilter, function(error) {
                            if (error) {
                                pipeline.release();
                                return callback(error);
                            }
                            faceOverlayFilter.connect(calleeWebRtcEndpoint, function(error) {
                                if (error) {
                                    pipeline.release();
                                    return callback(error);
                                }
                                calleeWebRtcEndpoint.connect(callerWebRtcEndpoint, function(error) {
                                    if (error) {
                                        pipeline.release();
                                        return callback(error);
                                    }
                                });
                                self.pipeline = pipeline;
                                self.webRtcEndpoint[callerId] = callerWebRtcEndpoint;
                                self.webRtcEndpoint[calleeId] = calleeWebRtcEndpoint;
                                callback(null);
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: Your code seems fine. In any case, check if both endpoints are negotiated in chrome://webrtc-internals or in about:webrtc from FF. The `ICEConnectionState` should be `connected`

Comment: By the way, you'll need to store the `faceOverlayFilter`, as you are doing with the others: `self.faceOverlayFilter = faceOverlayFilter`. Also, you won't need to pass `{useDataChannels: true}`, as the filter does not use data channels. It just doesn't work the way RTCPeerConnection data channels work, it's only for filters sending information.

Comment: After watching the WebRTC info in FF I see that the ICE status is "suceeded" but the connection to the server has gone.  Node.js application server tells  `reconnect to server 0 100 5cd07fc9-d5b9-4191-86b3-6131b43d0974
reconnect to server 1 100 5cd07fc9-d5b9-4191-86b3-6131b43d0974
reconnect to server 2 200 5cd07fc9-d5b9-4191-86b3-6131b43d0974
reconnect to server 3 300 5cd07fc9-d5b9-4191-86b3-6131b43d0974`

Comment: Also, I've stored the `faceOverlayFilter` as you said.  The datachannels is another feature I was testing but it does not have any importance in the issue I'm having.

Comment: @igracia must both endpoints exchange sdp between each other even the filter is in the middle?

Comment: @igracia I don't understand why putting a filter between a working communication between two peers can mess up everything like that!  If the ICE connection worked well in the one2one tutorial, why can't now put it working now?! The `about:webrtc` section tells me that the connection state is a success but the media server ends the execution unexpectedly... I don't know what to do now

Comment: I've checked your exact same code, and it works! What version of KMS are you using?

Comment: @igracia `kurento-media-server -v` command says I have 6.4.0 version

Comment: After you said that my code actually works I've uninstalled Kurento and all of it's installation archives (media server modules, core files, development tools...) and performed a clean install.  Now the code works as intended!  I think something broke the functionality of KMS.  I've been developing and installing custom KMS modules and it may cause the dysfunction.  Many thanks @igracia for your help and also for your teammates for this great project!

Comment: No worries! Glad to know you solved that.